# Blur Body Background with only jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, blur

I have looked but I could not find an answer. I would like to blur the background of body using jQuery. I would like to animate it. I have seen blur.js but I don't know if I can animate it and I can't figure out how to apply it to the body background. I am new to JS.

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    background-image: url(../images/background.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
}
```

Comment: You can simply create a `width:100%;height:100%` div, apply blur.js to it, and then animate the opacity with `.fadeIn(...)`.

Comment: You can blur using only css if you want (no jquery needed):

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheIronDeveloper/nq20w3bn/)

Comment: I have almost figured it out. How can I add css to body:before from jQuery. I want to do it after delay and animate it. It is "-webkit-filter: blur(2px);"